# python distinguish number and string solution

Tags: python, string, numbers

I'm new to python and trying  to solve the distinguish between number and string
For example :

- Input: 111aa111aa
- Output : Number: 111111 , String : aaaa

Comment: You could write a regex for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer
for numbers

```
import re
x = '111aa111aa'
num = ''.join(re.findall(r'[\d]+',x))
```

for alphabets

```
import re
x = '111aa111aa'
alphabets = ''.join(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]', x))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `in-built` functions as [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) and [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)

```
>>> x = '111aa111aa'
>>> number = ''.join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()])
'111111'
>>> string = ''.join([i for i in x if i.isalpha()])
'aaaa'
```

Or You can use `regex` here :

```
>>> x = '111aa111aa'
>>> import re
>>> numbers = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', x))
'111111'
>>> string = ''.join(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]', x))
'aaaa'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`isalpha`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isalpha.htm) for strings and [`isdigit`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm) for numbers,

```
In [45]: a = '111aa111aa'
In [47]: ''.join([i for i in a if i.isalpha()])
Out[47]: 'aaaa'
In [48]: ''.join([i for i in a if i.isdigit()])
Out[48]: '111111'
```

OR

```
In [18]: strings,numbers = filter(str.isalpha,a),filter(str.isdigit,a)

In [19]: print strings,numbers
aaaa 111111
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_string = '111aa111aa'
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, my_string))
'111111'
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, my_string))
'aaaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are new to Python, most of the presented approaches using `str.join` with list comprehensions or functional styles are quite sufficient.  Alternatively, I present some options using [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) that can help organize data, starting from basic to intermediate examples with arguably increasing intricacy.

Basic Alternative

```
# Dictionary
d = {"Number":"", "String":""}
for char in s:
    if char.isdigit():
        d["Number"] += char
    elif char.isalpha():
        d["String"] += char
d
# {'Number': '111111', 'String': 'aaaa'}
d["Number"]                                                # access by key
# '111111'

import collections as ct

# Default Dictionary
dd = ct.defaultdict(str)
for char in s:
    if char.isdigit():
        dd["Number"] += char
    elif char.isalpha():
        dd["String"] += char
dd
```