# Simplified way to know whats a number or not in python

Tags: python, number-formatting

I know that the stack overflow community had asked this question before, but, is there a way to make a python script that separates out numbers and letters **in a simplified way**?

edit: i need to make a script that can separate numbers **and** letters not only numbers or letters

Comment: Do you want to "sort out numbers and letters" or "to know whats a number or not"?

Comment: This question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046242/how-to-sort-the-letters-in-a-string-alphabetically-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python distinguish number and string solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016557/python-distinguish-number-and-string-solution)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is pretty vague, and it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Please provide an **example** of what the inputs are, and the desired behavior of the program. Explain why the other SO answers are not satisfactory for your use case.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by _sorts out_. Having to do this kind of operation can sometimes be a sign that you programmed yourself into a corner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating one list and running through it in order to create two lists, one filled with number and the other with letters, sorting them individually and, if necessary, combining into one.

```
>>> a, b, c = [12, 43, "g", 9, "a", "x"], [], []
>>> for i in a:
...     try:
...             i = int(i)
...             b.append(i)
...     except:
...             if i == str(i):
...                     c.append(i)
...
>>> b = sorted(b)
>>> c = sorted(c)
>>> b
[9, 12, 43]
>>> c
['a', 'g', 'x']
>>> d = b + c #order : numbers, then letters
>>> d
[9, 12, 43, 'a', 'g', 'x']
```

Comment: this is very helpful but i need to put it in a file

Comment: Rewrite it in the format you require... And if it is the solution that helps you. mark it as a solution by clicking on the little tick next to my answer. And welcome to Stack Overflow!